# How to truncate a table with a prepared statement in Doctrine2

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

I'm doing:

```
    $truncateSQL = 'TRUNCATE TABLE :tableName';
    $stmtTruncate = $em->getConnection()->prepare($truncateSQL);
    $stmtTruncate->bindValue('tableName',$this->tableName);
    $stmtTruncate->execute();
```

But getting the error:

```
[PDOException]                                                                                                       
  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that  
   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''image_sizes_t'' at line 1
```

Are the quotes round the table name the problem here? `$this->tableName` is just a string

Answer (score 1):

You can't use table or column names in as placeholders in prepared statements as `'table_name'` is invalid MySql syntax.

if you need to make your column / table names safe you can wrap them in backticks.

```
 "`".$table_name."`"
```